# JUnit Eclipse show System.out.print()'s

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, console, system

I am using JUnit 3 with Eclipse 3.4. When I run a JUnit test case everything works fine and the test completes perfectly. Only thing is I want to see the output of the classes that I am running.  All the classes have basic System.out.print() to some output values. So when I run the tests I don't see any console messages at all. How do I get Eclipse to show System.out.print() output in Console window when a test is successful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe other program was running on the console of Eclipse too. Please ensure Eclipse displays the active view of your JUnit code.

From Eclipse Help:

> Select the “Display Selected Console” command to bring the console selected from the resulting list into focus.
>   Note: this command is only enabled if you have more than one console open.

Comment: Thanks that was the case...For some reason I had multiple views for console, and when I'd run JUnit it would create a new console view but the old one was hidden where the System.outs would go to.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I also met the problem before:)

Answer (score 3):

jUnit does not suppress System.out statements. If the statement is hit during the test run, then it is executed and writes to `System.out` which is, when executed within eclipse (Run Configuration), the console window.

But maybe you've redirected `System.out` to write to a file or a log.

Comment: Nope there is not redirection at all.  I am using Eclipse's "Run as Junit test".  If I run the code normally the Console shows the Sys.outs.  If I run the same classes using the JUnit in Eclipse, The Console window is blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the stack trace (and not System.out) in the Console, instead of in the `Failure Trace` window, select the "Show Stack Trace In Console View" button:

[image]

click on the button as show above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i solve it putting @Test above the function test with the output, and that solved it ... Hoping that this can help ... :)