# How to pass parameters to jUnit not from Ant (in Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I would like to pass some parameters to jUnit while testing. I know, for example, that it can be set showoutput to 'yes'.

How to do this from command line or from Eclipse run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Params can be passed to Java like this:

```
java com.example.foo.bar -Dparam1=val1 -Dparam2=val2
```

So, running jUnit and passing params works in the same manner, create a new configuration, and pass the params as VM options.

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore -Dparam1=val1 [test class]
```

Comment: Showoutput looks like an JUnit Ant task parameter, not something passed on the command line.  This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001068/junit-eclipse-show-system-out-prints indicates that the output will always be printed.